# onBackPressed to Home Fragment from another Fragment in Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, onbackpressed

In my app I have created a Navigation Drawer with six Fragments. The MainOption Fragment is not included in the Navigation item menu list. Now I want to activate Back button on mobile device to redirect to Main Fragment. For example if I have fragments A,B,C,D,E,F, and now if I click B, then if I press back button, it will back to A. In the same way if I Press back button on Fragment E it will redirect to Fragment A. Now how can I achive this logic in my code. Hence I have tried lots of code from the website, but nothis was working at all. Here is my code snepet for Navigation Drawer

```
private NavigationView navigationView;
private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
private Toolbar toolbar ;
private View navigationHeader;
private ImageView imgProfile;
private TextView txtName, txtWebsite;

// flag to load home fragment when user presses back key
private boolean shouldLoadHomeFragOnBackPress = true;
private Handler mHandler;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    mHandler = new Handler();

    drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

    // Navigation view header
    navigationHeader= navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
    txtName = navigationHeader.findViewById(R.id.username);
    txtWebsite = navigationHeader.findViewById(R.id.email);
    imgProfile = navigationHeader.findViewById(R.id.profile_image);

    // load nav menu header data
    loadNavHeader();

    //Set the Home Fragment initially
    OptionMenuFragment fragment = new OptionMenuFragment();
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment, "OptionMenuFragment");
    fragmentTransaction.commit();

    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
 }

 private void loadNavHeader() {
    // name, website
    txtName.setText("Hallo");
    txtWebsite.setText("mail.com");
    imgProfile.setImageResource(R.drawable.profile_image);

    //ToDo: Image should be uploaded from web
}

 String lastFragmentTag;
 boolean showingFirstFragment = true;

 public void addNewFragment(Fragment fragment, String fragmentTag) {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

    if (lastFragmentTag != null) {
        Fragment currentFragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(lastFragmentTag);
        transaction.remove(currentFragment);
    } else {
        Fragment currentFragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
        transaction.hide(currentFragment);
    }

    transaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment, fragmentTag);
    transaction.commit();

    lastFragmentTag = fragmentTag;
    showingFirstFragment = false;

 }
 @Override
 public void onBackPressed() {
    //Here we're gonna remove the last fragment added, and show OptionMenuFragment again
    if (!showingFirstFragment)
    {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

        Fragment firstFragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("OptionMenuFragment");
        Fragment currentFragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(lastFragmentTag);

        transaction.remove(currentFragment);
        transaction.show(firstFragment);

        transaction.commit();

        showingFirstFragment = true;
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
 }


 @Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
 }

 @Override
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.blu_home) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainOptionPage.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
  }


 @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
 @Override
 public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    String fragmentTag=null;
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    Fragment fragment = null;
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.view_profile:
            fragment = new ViewProfileFragment();
            fragmentTag = "ViewProfileFragment";
            break;
        case R.id.todo_list:
            fragment =new ToDoListFragment();
            fragmentTag="ToDoListFragment";
            break;
        case R.id.logout:
            showAlertDialogLogOut();
            break;
        case R.id.settings:
            fragment = new SettingsFragment();
            fragmentTag="SettingFragment";
            break;
        case R.id.about:
            fragment = new AboutFragment();
            fragmentTag="AboutFragment";
            break;
        case R.id.info:
            fragment=new InfoFragment();
            fragmentTag="InfoFragment";
            break;
    }
    if(fragment!=null){
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment).commit();
    }
    drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
 }

 private void showAlertDialogLogOut() {

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    builder.setTitle("Logout");
    builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to log out?");

    builder.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // close the dialog, go to login page
            dialog.dismiss();
            startActivity(new Intent(MainOptionPage.this, LoginPage.class));
        }
    });

    builder.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // Do nothing
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For that approach, you will want to use the add(containerViewId, fragment, tag) method instead of replace(containerViewId, fragment), since replace will call remove(Fragment) for ALL fragments previously added to the container, before adding the new fragment. Also, you will want to use addToBackStack(name).

Here's a method I created for a project, and slightly modified for you:

```
String lastFragmentTag;
boolean showingFirstFragment = true;

public void addNewFragment(Fragment fragment, String fragmentTag) {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

    if (lastFragmentTag != null) {
        Fragment currentFragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(lastFragmentTag);
        transaction.remove(currentFragment);
    } else {
        Fragment currentFragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
        transaction.hide(currentFragment);
    }

    transaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment, fragmentTag);
    transaction.commit();

    lastFragmentTag = fragmentTag;
    showingFirstFragment = false;
}
```

Then you just have to make this change inside onNavigationItemSelected:

```
Fragment fragment = null;
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

String fragmentTag;

switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.view_profile:
        fragment = new ViewProfileFragment();
        fragmentTag = "ViewProfileFragment";

        break;
    ...
}

if(fragment!=null){
        addNewFragment(fragment, fragmentTag);
}
```

Where "fragmentTag", is going to be a String variable which you change according to the fragment instantiated.

EDIT: Some more changes since the code wasn't working as intended:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    //Here we're gonna remove the last fragment added, and show OptionMenuFragment again
    if (!showingFirstFragment)
    {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

        Fragment firstFragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("OptionMenuFragment");
        Fragment currentFragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(lastFragmentTag);

        transaction.remove(currentFragment);
        transaction.show(firstFragment);

        transaction.commit();

        showingFirstFragment = true;
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

And when adding OptionMenuFragment, do this instead:

```
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment, "OptionMenuFragment");
```

Comment: the fragment tag is not clear to me. Is it the homeFragment or can you please explain a bit more. This code is not working

Comment: a fragment tag will uniquely identify each of your Fragments, so you can later get them again with fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(tag). I edited the answer, hope it's clearer now.

Comment: @Tharius Thanks. It might be offtopic. But I need to know that. Do I have to declare each of the fragment initially. for example string ViewProfileTag, string ToDoList etc...

Comment: The problem in this code is, in this way all the other fragments are loded on the MainOptionMenu Page. Its like overloaded the main page withh the fragments. But I want to replace the mainOptionMenu page while loading the other fragments.

Comment: Shall I modify only my onBackPressed() methos and then in oncreate method I will modify the Optionmenu fragment transaction. I have another question how can I get showingFirstFragment variable inside the onBackpress methos. I mean shall I initialize like this boolean  showingFirstFragment=true; Hence I have modified my code. but still it is not working

Comment: I made some changes to the addNewFragment method, you'll have to replace it too. The showingFirstFragment boolean has to be initialized globally so you can access in inside onBackPressed. Just initialize it above onCreate, like "private boolean showingFirstFragment = true", or you can just use your "shouldLoadHomeFragOnBackPress" var instead.